# Disable gesture on sideViews in contentView

Tags: swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm showing three views in my collectionView cell. one full in middle and preview of next and previous at the corner of the contentView. And using panGesture for swipe up the middle view. How i can disable panGesture on side views?

Here is the image : [image]

I have added panGestureRecognizer on content view. but i don't want side view to recognize the gesture and also i want to make side images quite faint in color. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. Implement method:

```
func wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        print("was dragged began")
    }
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
        print("was dragged change \(gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view))")
        testTouches(touches: gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view))
    }
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        print("was dragged ended")
    }
}
```

Than implement method to test touches points:

```
func testTouches(touches: CGPoint) {
    // Get location of touch

    let touchLocation = touches
    // Convert the location of the side views to this view controller's view coordinate system
    let sideViewFrame = self.view.convert(sideView.frame, from: sideView.superview)// Check if touch is inside side view
    if sideViewFrame.contains(touchLocation) {
            // do nothing
        }
        else {
            // do something
        }
}
```